# System.TypeLoadException: Error trying to use web service in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

I'm building an app to retrieve data from an online SQL database using the Xamarin Android platform in visual studio. I created a web service that retrieves the values from the database using MySqlConnection from the library MySql.Data.MySqlClient. I then created an intent to connect the main activity and the service which is invoked after a button click. The app app starts up fine but when I press the button I get this message: Unhandled Exception:

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.PerformanceMonitor' from assembly 'MySql.Data,
>   Version=6.3.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d'.